# print and count the number of permutation (without using stl next_permutation)

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I'm a C programmer and trying to get better at C++. I want to implement a permutation function (without using the STL algorithms). I came up with the following algorithm (out of my C way of thinking), but

```
a) it crashes for k > 2 (I suppose because the element that the iterator 
   points to, gets deleted, is inserted back and then incremented).
b) erase/insert operation seem unnecessary.
```

How would the C++ experts amongst you implement it?

```
template <class T>
class Ordering {
    public:
          Ordering(int n);
          int combination(int k);
          int permutation(int k);
    private:
          set<T> elements;
          vector<T> order;
}

template <class T>
int Ordering<T>::permutation (int k) {
    if (k > elements.size()) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (k == 0) {
        printOrder();
        return 1;
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (typename set<T>::iterator it = elements.begin();
        it != elements.end();
        it++
    )
    {
        order[k-1] = *it;
        elements.erase(*it);
        count += permutation(k-1);
        elements.insert(*it);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: If it crashes, then you should probably debug it.

Comment: If it didn't crash, it wouldn't be C thinking, would it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ironically, it breaks due to a detail deep in the bowels of the standard library. Funny, isn't it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your iteration over the `elements` set. You try to increment an iterator which you have removed. That cannot work.

If you insist in using this approach, you must store the successor of `it`, before calling `set::erase`. That means you have to move the incrementation part of your for loop *into* the loop.

Like this:

```
for (typename set<T>::iterator it = elements.begin();
    it != elements.end();
    /* nothing here */
)
{
    order[k-1] = *it;
    typename set<T>::iterator next = it;
    ++next;
    elements.erase(*it);
    count += permutation(k-1);
    elements.insert(order[k-1]);
    it = next;
}
```

---

Edit: One possible way of temporarily "removing" objects from your set would be to have a `std::set<std::pair<T,bool>>` and simply write `it->second = false` and afterwards `it->second = true`. Then, while iterating, you can *skip* entries where the second value is `false`. This adds a bit of an overhead since you have to do a lot more work while descending. But inserting+removing elements adds a logarithmic overhead every time, which is probably worse.

If you used a (custom) linked list (perhaps you can even get `std::list` to do that) you could very inexpensively remove and re-insert objects.

Comment: Makes sense. And I confirmed that it works. Is there any other way to exclude the already selected elements, without modifying the set?    If it were a vector instead, I could have swapped elements and created the permutations in-place.

Comment: @zonked.zonda: See my edit. The first paragraph still tries to keep your set, while the last paragraph is probably what you want. It's reasonably fast, and if you use a custom allocator in the constructor of your type, I would have a hard time coming up with an even faster solution (especially since we don't know what `T` is).